# combining jackson objectmapper and stream parsing

Tags: android, performance

I have an android application, where parsing a json block takes around 250ms. It contains an array, and I only really need the first 6-7 values available immediatly. And I really need to speed up getting to those pieces of the data.

I have a data structure that essentially looks like:

```
class Data {
    List<Map> data = objectmapper_readvalue_data;

    public HashMap getItem(int i) {
        return data.get(i);
    }
}
```

I was really hoping to do something like this with a JsonParser:
    class Data {
        List data = new List();
        JsonParser p;

```
    public HashMap getItem(int i) {
        while (data.length < i) {
            data.append(p.parseOneBlockOfData());
        }
        return data.get(i);
    }
}
```

And only the first 5-6 values will be parsed at the first render, the others I can deal with later. However, I'm missing the "parseOneBlockOfData" function. Of course I can use a StringBuilder to buffer every value in the parse until I find the next entire block, then use a objectParser or that, but I'm not sure what the performance will be like.

Are there any non hackish ways of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

incase anyone googles this:

```
JsonParser parser = objectMapper.getFactory().createJsonParser(inputStream);

// Keep going until we find filters:
String fieldName = null;
JsonToken token = null;
while (!"filters".equals(fieldName)) {
    token = parser.nextToken();
    while (token != JsonToken.START_ARRAY) {
        token = parser.nextToken();
    }
    fieldName = parser.getCurrentName();
}
// We're at the filters node

while (parser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT) {
    Map x = objectMapper.readValue(parser, Map.class);
}
```